# tomcat processParameters complains about "invalid chunk ignored"

Tags: tomcat, logging

I am hosting a software system running under tomcat for quite a number of customers. Some of these send invalid URLs as request. These URLs may contain "&=" or "&&", which is not within the http specs. Now my tomcat complains about the following: "08.09.2010 12:36:04 org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters processParameters WARNING: Parameters: Invalid chunk '' ignored."

It is no problem, as is doesn't affect the operation in any way. Only problem ist that the tomcat/logs/catalina.out is growing with every single request.

In the net you can find suggestions like: - Fix your URLs (which I can't, as it is the customers who send them) - Raise tomcats log level to ERROR (which I don't want to do, as it would suppress INFO like "INFO: Reloading context [/ContextName]" and other stuff you want to know. - Redirect the log to the application log (which won't solve the problem, as the message will flood just another log)

Does anyone know how to solve the problem at its ROOT, which means: Tell tomcat not to complain about invalid request parameters any longer

Answer (score 6):

yeehah, found it myself ;-)

After digging into the source code of tomcat I realized that I can easily disbale WARNINGS for org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters by adding the following line to tomcat/conf/logging.properties

org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.level=SEVERE

One server restart and it is quiet!

Comment: Yes - this has been an irritation for years. THank you @cgicgi and SO!  It's a completely useless message, should be a return value from a URLSanitizer or something.

Comment: In the case of Payara / Glassfish: set the Log Level of org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.Parameters to WARNING, and save. (server-config > Logger Settings > Log Levels).